# Where is this contract's string written and viewable?

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I have a very simply contract.  I am testing writing to the blockchain (on a private network).  The contract seems to deploy successfully but I don't see "this is a hardcoded string" anywhere on my block explorer.

Can anyone help me to create a simple contract where I can write "Hello World" in a way that is viewable on the blockchain?

Here is the code I'm using now:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract TestString {

    string testStr;

    function TestString() {
        testStr = "this is hardcoded string";
    }

    function setString(string str) {
        testStr = str;
    }

    function getString() constant returns (string) {
        return testStr;
    }

    function() payable {
        revert();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethereum defines a "World State" that contains all of the contracts storages. It is not directly part of the blockchain, but is the result of applying all the transactions.

You cannot see it directly. But you can make queries to the contract, and the contract can return appropiate values. In you example you can call the `getString()` and it will return the appropiate value.

You can query an arbitrary contract storage directly using [web3.eth.getStorageAt](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetstorageat). But it is not very user friendly, it is more a debugging tool.